# How to find the center of an after-rotated rectangle in 2d-space?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I'm trying to write an algorithm that solves the following problem. And although there is a lot of rectangle geometry questions here on math.stackexchange.com, I have not yet found one that answers the following dilemma.

I have the top-left coordinate of a rectangle, along with the height and width of the rectangle. I also have an angle that the rectangle has been rotated by (emphasis on past tense). The point of rotation is the center of the after-rotated rectangle.

Given the above information, I would like to find the center of the after-rotated rectangle.

Right now my approach is to first find the other three coordinates, and then take the average of the x and y components giving the center.
The other co-ordinates calculated by first finding which quadrant I am in, and then using simple trigonometry to find new point.

For example, if the angle $0<a\leq 90$, I would find the top right point by first calculating the y component with $(-1 * sin(a)*width)$ and the x component with $(cos(a) * width)$.

Doing it this way I end up with a LOT of `if` statements, and alot of different calculations, some multiplied by $-1$ depending on which quadrant.

If there is a more elegant way to solve this problem, please help guide me through it.

Update:

I have included a diagram to illustrate.

[image]

Comment: Is the rectangle rotated about its top-left corner?

Comment: I’m having trouble deciphering your description what’s getting rotated where. An illustrated example would be helpful.

Comment: I suspect that you’re not going to be able to avoid a case analysis since the corner of the rectangle that ends up as the top left one depends on the rotation angle.

Comment: @PeterForeman, no, it's rotated at the center of the after-rotated rectangle. [@]amd, sure, I will mock up an illustrated example now, and I do hope it's not dependant upon case analysis, my trigonometry skills aren't all that, I hope there is a more elegant way.